# Python BigQuery script bigquery.jobs.create error

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-iam

I am trying to run a simple query on Google BigQuery via a python script, but am getting the below error that my service account is missing `bigquery.jobs.create` permission.

My service Account has the following roles applied:

- Owner
- BigQuery Admin
- BigQuery Job User

I've also tried creating a custom role with `bigquery.jobs.create` and applying that to the service account, but still consistently get this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

project_id = "my-test-project"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("credentials.json")

client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=project_id
)

print(client.project) # returns "my-test-project"
query = client.query("select 1 as test;")
```

> Access Denied: Project my-test-project: The user my-service-account @
>   my-test-project. iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have
>   bigquery.jobs.create permission in project my-test-project.

Comment: Hey @fez, have you tried using `client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("credentials.json")`? I doubt it will make a difference, but just curious.

Comment: @Dascienz yes that works thanks! Will accept as the solution if you add as an answer!

Comment: Hey @fez, really happy that your issue was a simple fix! Happy computing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating the client using `client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json("credentials.json")` is the preferred method to avoid "Access Denied" errors. For one reason or another (I'm not sure why since bigquery does use oauth 2.0 access tokens to authorize requests), setting credentials through `google.oauth2.service_account` can lead to permission issues.